# Sql - Sum function used in conjunction with case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

hope everyone is doing well in the new years 2015. I am using a nateeza/aginity api to run the below query. it is a sum function used in conjuction with a case statement.

```
    Select ID1,ID2,SeqNo, sum(case when e.cust_no is not null then 1 else 0 end) as countofcustnumber
from tableA
left join table b on a.value1=b.value1
left join table c on b.value2=c.value2
left join table d on c.id_no=d.id_no
left join table e on d.cust_no=e.cust_no
group by id1,id2,seqno
having sum(case when e.cust_no is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 
--having sum(case when e.cust_no is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

The idea behind this is to use the first having statement to produce a data set of all id1,id2,seqno which have no cust_no affiliated to them. The second having statement which is commented out at the moment should produce a data set of all id1, id2, seqno which have atleast one cust_no affiliated to them, if my logic is correct.

However when i run this query, i see that there is a bunch of id1,id2,seqno showing in the resultant data set with cust_no not null for the first having statement that is not commented out..

Can some one please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: currently when i use the first having statement i get the below result:

```
ID1 ID2 SEQNO, COUNTOFcustnumber 
a1  c1   123    0
a2  c2   456    0
```

But when I go and dig into ID a1 which has a bunch of customers associated to that ID, i see that there are customers with a valid customer #. The whole point of this query is to find a list of IDs which have customers with no valid customer #, if that makes sense. That is why i used countofcustnumber, the 0 indicates no customer has a valid customer id.

Currently on deeper analysis, I find that if i take the first result set ID = a1, ID2 = c1 and SeqNo = 123 there is the following customer related to a1/c1/123. I used the following query to find out the customers

```
  Select ID1,ID2,SeqNo, d.id_no, e.cust_no    from tableA
left join table b on a.value1=b.value1
left join table c on b.value2=c.value2
left join table d on c.id_no=d.id_no
left join table e on d.cust_no=e.cust_no
where ID1 in ('a1')
```

I get the results:

```
a1  c1  123  d1  3456
```

Note: a1 was gotten from running the query at the begining of my post not the one directly above.

I was expecting the result:

```
a1  c1  123  d1   null
```

or

```
a1  c1  123  null  null
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can you include a sample result set from the query as it stands?

Comment: Hey Yosi, the question is am I tabulating the results for the cust_no that is null and not null correctly using that sum / case statement? As of this moment when I run this query it gives me a set of results which do not match what i specified in the case statement. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong with the sum case statement

Comment: Hey Mark, I will put in some results to make this clearer

Comment: I have added a sample result set.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you go and look at id = a1, id2 = c1, and seqno = 123 you see there is a cust_no?

Comment: yes this is correct Jchao, but i figured using the above query logic I would not see a cust_no since the sum (case) function should only display the instances where the sum is 0 which means no cust_no is found.

Comment: In the example shown, the results all show a count of 0 - which is exactly what you would expect from a having sum(...)=0 condition. From your results, it looks as though there are no corresponding customers on table e that correspond to id = a1, id2 = c1, and seqno = 123, and your existing query is working as it should. What happens if you amend the query to remove the group by and having clauses, add a `where id = a1 and id2 = c1 and seqno = 123` condition and change the select to `select e.custno` ?

Comment: correct, so while it looks like there are no corresponding customers on table e that map to id = a1, id2 = c1 and seqno = 123, when i take that id = a1 and query it individually and do deeper analysis as you suggested by removing the group by and having clauses, I find that there are infact customers that are valid for id = a1 and id2 = c1 and seqno = 123. This is what is throwing me off, so while the query appears to work from a visual stand point on deeper analysis I find it is posting wrong data.

Comment: What I meant was, can you add the results to the question when you amend the query as suggested? It might be helpful if you could include some sample data for each of the tables, as well.

Comment: ok Mark i added my results as to what I am seeing, hope this helps.

Comment: Those results are not possible with those values and those queries - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/128749/3 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15be9/1 . (The first shows data that would return 0 customers on tableE, the second shows data that matches what you say you find.) Are you sure your case statement wasn't on `d.custno` instead of `e.custno`? That would give results like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/128749/5

Comment: Thanks Mark, and interesting choice in picking sqlfiddle.com. I did not know about this site. Learn something new every day. BTW I did figure out  my issue, at first i was breaking my head thinking it was the sum(case) combo but it was a mistake in my query. I wrote the query correctly here, but after reviewing what i had in the aginity editor, i was using a column value which shouldn't have been included. After i removed that column value, the query worked fine. I made the assumption that it was something to do with my sum (case) statement.